# Not allow insecure connections on nginx

Tags: nginx, certificate, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I installed certbot certificate for nginx:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com
```

and redirect all http to https:

```
# Redirect non-https traffic to https
if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
```

It is working from browser, but I still can make insecure connection via

```
curl --insecure example.com
```

Here are the main configurations in nginx.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  if ($scheme != "https") {
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
  location / {
    root /www/html/;
    ...
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
  } 
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by 
 Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed 
  by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
  proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem;
  proxy_ssl_verify on;
  proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
}
```

When I issue 
      curl -iI https://example.com, it returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 04 Jul 2018 09:19:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1218
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Jul 2018 12:10:25 GMT
ETag: W/"Zwtf1TTMBhoSbg9LZvHbCg=="
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

Answer (score 1):

it should return `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`, in which user agent [may or may not](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2) redirect to new location.

use `-L` or `--location` switch in your curl command to automatically follow the redirections.

Edit 2018-07-05:

> Here are the main configurations in nginx.conf:

Though that's not a bad config, `if` directive usage is [discouraged](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).
You'd better split the config into two separate `server` block, one for http, and other for https.

Something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    
    # log your http request if you need to
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example-com_error.log notice;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example-com_access.log combined;

    # certbot endpoint
    location ~ ^/\.well-known/ {
        root /var/www/certbot/;
        access_log off;
    }
    
    # other requests should end up here
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    
    # log your http request if you need to
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example-com_error.log notice;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example-com_access.log combined;

    # default document root and document index
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;
    
    # SSL cert, private key, and configurations.
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    # https configurations
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80; # why would you proxy_pass back to nginx again?
        
        # you only need this if your proxy_pass uses https, not http like this example.
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem;
        proxy_ssl_verify on;
        proxy_ssl_verify_depth 2;
    }
}
```

should suffice.

> When I issue curl -iI https://example.com, it returns:

yes, why it wouldn't return a `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`?

The insecure part of `--insecure` flag in cURL only **disables HTTPS certificate validation**, i.e. you can use invalid SSL certificate in your HTTPS request (bad CN, bad SAN, bad expiry date, bad CA, self signed, etc) and cURL will still satisfy your request instead of failing hard.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But, when I try to curl some of my api,      curl -i https://example.com/api/path/ it returns http and page, not "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"

Comment: it'll help a lot if you add more information on your question, such as `curl -iI http://example.com/api/path` output, your nginx configuration, and your access/error logs.

Comment: When I try to curl some of my api,      curl -i https://example.com/api/path/ it returns http and page, not "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently", but when I  try curl http://example.com/api/path it returns "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently".

Comment: You need to post your entire nginx.conf. Also using an `if` directive like that for redirecting http -> https is a bad way of doing it.

Comment: Is there any way to not allow curl --insecure https://example.com to satisfy request and return  HTTP/1.1 200 OK? I would like to stop any HTTP requests to be satisfied.

Comment: @coding no. `--insecure` flag always specified by client, i.e. if client wishes to ignore certificate validation, so be it.

Specifying `--insecure` doesn't mean it doesn't use HTTPS though, try using `--location` flag to follow redirects, and it should redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

In modern browsers you can use [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security](HSTS) to force browsers load HTTPS instead of HTTP; but not in cURL though.